# I need to block according to some value from response

Tags: java, request, struts2, response

I'm working on improving my web vulnerability scanner. I have to add a vulnerability in Struts framework that I have never experienced before.

I found the showcase containing S02-45. My web scanners payload is on http header;

```
Content-Type: .multipart/form-data~%{#context["com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse"].addHeader("a",268719111-309892)}
```

and if there is a value in the response like this;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 

a: 268409219
```

I confirm the vulnerability. Confirms by making 4 requests and looking at the response. But I wonder what happens if I get block after the second request? 
So Can I block according to the value in response or request? In struts framework

Good luck with!!

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please edit your question to provide specific details of what you have tried, and why it is not working. Include your code and any error messages you get.

Comment: If you are writing such a scanner then it should not make requests. There's also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500460/573032